# Submit several forms with one button in Wordpress form manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, wordpress, onclick

The problem is that these forms are generated with shortcodes, and I suspect that my created button, which leads to submission form1 and then form2 do not work because of them.

Here how it looks:

Original buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" id="fm_form_submit" class="submit" value="Siųsti" onclick="return fm_submit_onclick(1)">
<input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" id="fm_form_submit" class="submit" value="Siųsti" onclick="return fm_submit_onclick(2)">
<input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" id="fm_form_submit" class="submit" value="Siųsti" onclick="return fm_submit_onclick(2)">
```

What I am doing:

```
<input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" id="fm_form_submit" class="submit" value="Siųsti" onclick="DoAllThese()">
```

and then:

```
function DoAllThese() {
return fm_submit_onclick(1);
return fm_submit_onclick(2);
return fm_submit_onclick(3);
}
```

Any leads what can be wrond with it?

Comment: The function returns after the first `return`, that is `return fm_submit_onclick(1);`. Even if you modify the code by removing all the `return`s then it will work but any validation that these functions were doing will be lost

Comment: This doen't work. It fails after the first `return`

Comment: Yeah, I understand now... Don't know what to do, it seems to be a dead end, because plugin structure is not what I would want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and this is part of the solution I used (this isn't fancy, but it usually works):

```
    function subMultForms() {

     document.getElementById('form').submit();
     document.getElementById('form_two').submit();

    };
```

Then call the `function` with a click event on the desired element. Also, I'm not sure if the top `inputs` are part of your mark-up — if they are — they all share the same `Id` which isn't valid and can lead to problems.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the problem is that my IDs are the same, they only have different onClick functions. And I need to do all of these functions on one click. But as people above said, after first returning function everything after it fails. Mayby someone knows how it could be prevented?
Beside, about your code, if I would change IDs of these forms to unique ones, everything would be ok? Just asking, because I can't understant how it will submit all these information if plugin won't understand this part of code, because it seems to be out of context for my plugin. Am I wrong?

Comment: It all depends where the `ID` is being used and for what purpose, like I stated earlier, it's not valid to use duplicate `ID's`. I'm just guessing, because I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve— you might be able to combine all the form content into one `form`. What plugin are you using?